# Best way to avoid repeating code when using addEventListener and functions

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, dom, events

im pretty new at coding, currently studing front end dev. I´m on my 5:th week learning JS and got a challange to create a toDo list with Typescript.

When i create a task in my app it has a checkbox and a "trash"-button. The idéa of the trash button is pretty clear and the checkbox is going put the task last in the list when its "checked".

I noticed some repetative code  while creating my event listeners. So I found a way to add the event listener to multiple elements but I can't wrap my head around how to call the different functions that corresponds to what was clicked.

this is how I found a way to add the event listener to each element. But from here, how can I call a function based on what was clicked?

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.add-click-listener').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click',  event => {

        })
    })
```

this was the code from the beginning

```
    let checkbox = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-checkbox'));
    checkbox.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', checkboxStatusShift);
    });
    
    let trashBtn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trash-btn')); 
    trashBtn.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
    });
```

this will be the function to "trash" a task:

```
function deleteTask(event: any) {
    const index = (event.currentTarget);
    const buttonId = index.id?.replace('remove-', '');
    const currentTask = todoDatabase.filter((object) => object.id === buttonId)[0];
    const currentTaskId = currentTask.id;
  
    console.log(buttonId);
    console.log(currentTaskId);
    

    if (buttonId == currentTaskId) {
        todoDatabase.splice(0, 1);
        printTodoList();
    }

}
```

I haven't started the code for the checkbox function yet.

Very grateful for any tips I can get.

Comment: 1. `array.filter(...)[0]` -> [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). 2. Careful with anonymous functions as event handler. You'll not be able to ever remove that event handler from that target. This may be OK, but it may also bite you in the butt later on.

Comment: Hi Thomas! Do I understand your 1. correct that you mean that I should switch filter to find? I would like to skip anonymous functions as much as possible, the thing is I dont know how to make my refactored addEventlistener call two diffrent functions based on what was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies, this pointed me in the right direction and I got it working as intended, the following code was the result:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.add-click-listener').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click',  (event: any) => {
            const thisWasClicked = event.currentTarget;
            let trashBtn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trash-btn'));

            const filterTrashBtn: any = trashBtn.find((btn) => btn.id === thisWasClicked.id);
            const findTask = trashBtn.indexOf(filterTrashBtn);

            if (filterTrashBtn?.id == thisWasClicked.id) {
                todoDatabase.splice(findTask, 1);
                printTodoList();

            }
                        
        });
        
    });
```

Now I can just write the code for my checkboxes with another if and some variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can avoid repeating code by using an event delegation pattern. You have to attach an event listener to the parent element, and then inside the handler to check if it matches your child element. The event by clicking on child will bubble so you will catch it. In code it will look like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#parent-element').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches('.child-element')) {
    // do your stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Oro! This I did not know, in your example is the "function(e)" concidered to be anonymous?, any how, tanks for your response, I'll give it a try.

Comment: yeah, in my example it is anonymous, but you can make it a variable or named function, and then you will able to remove listener if you need

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the root element where the checkboxes are located and handle the target element that fired the event.

If the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" /><label for="1">Checkbox 1</label>
    <input id="2" type="checkbox" /><label for="2">Checkbox 2</label>
    <input id="3" type="checkbox" /><label for="3">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

An example JS code could be as shown below:

```
const root = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxes')[0];
root.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const target = event.target;

  if (target.tagName == 'INPUT') {
    console.log(target.id);
    console.log(target.checked);
  }
});
```

Bind a click event to the root div with the class name "checkboxes" and handle who exactly fires the event.

If you can use Jquery then the same can be done with `on` function
https://api.jquery.com/on

```
$(div.checkboxes).on("click", ".checkbox", function(event){})
```

Comment: Hi Andrey! Thank you for your response! My checkbox is rendered out by JS. Each "task" is a div with an input with type checkbox, then a label and a button element. Does the example code still applys in that case?

Comment: I think yes. You can try it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sthdna?file=index.js
Just replace the html markup with your own.